# OpenGl with C++ - Textures

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, textures, texture-mapping

I'm trying to map some textures in OpenGl to a face of a cube. But, when I run my program my texture doesn't appear. So I have this block of code:

```
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texture[1]);

        glPushMatrix();

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);                                  // Begin drawing the color cube with 6 quads
                                                            // Top face (y = 1.0f)
                                                            // Define vertices in counter-clockwise (CCW) order with normal pointing out
        //glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Green
        glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -2.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -2.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -2.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -2.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);

                                                            // Bottom face (y = -1.0f)
        //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);     // Orange
        glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);

                                                            // Front face  (z = 1.0f)
        //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);     // Red
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);  glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);
        glTexCoord2f(10.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);
        glTexCoord2f(10.0f,10.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0f,10.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);

                                                            // Back face (z = -1.0f)
        //glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // Yellow
        glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);

                                                            // Left face (x = -1.0f)
        //glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Blue
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);

                                                            // Right face (x = 1.0f)
        //glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // Magenta
        glVertex3f(1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2,  1.0f+j*2);
        glVertex3f(1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
        glEnd();                                            // End of drawing color-cube

        glPopMatrix();

        glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

My Init function is this:

```
void initGL() {
     glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);                       // Set background color to black and opaque
     glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);                                    // Enable smooth shading
     cria_texturas();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
     //glClearDepth(1.0f);                                         // Set background depth to farthest
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);                                    // Enable depth testing for z-culling
     //glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);                                     // Set the type of depth-test
     //glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);          // Nice perspective corrections
}
```

To load a texture I have written this code that uses a premade class that loads the image:

```
glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
imag.LoadBmpFile("chao.bmp");
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3,
             imag.GetNumCols(),
             imag.GetNumRows(), 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             imag.ImageData());
```

So I don't understand why the texture doesn't appear in the face of the cube. Can you help me?

Comment: You're generating one texture to `texture[0]`, and then you're using `texture[1]`. You should be using `texture[0]` in `glBindTexture`. Also, you should call `glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before `cria_texturas()`.

Answer (score -1):

When using the immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd) the call of `glVertex` is finishing the build of one single vertex. Essentially what glVertex does is coalescing the attributes that have been placed in the other attribute "registers" and sends it into a buffer.

In your code you have the following:

```
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);  glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);
    glTexCoord2f(10.0f,0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2,  -2.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);
    glTexCoord2f(10.0f,10.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0f,10.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, 1.0f+j*2);

                                                        // Back face (z = -1.0f)

    glVertex3f( 1.0f+i*2, -4.0f+y*2, -1.0f+j*2);
```

**Only** the last of these glTexCoord calls actually has an effect, the other ones will just set the register, but that value gets immediately overwritten by the following calls.

The way to use immediate mode is

```
foreach vertex in model:
    glColor
    glNormal
    glTexCoord
    ...
    glVertex // must be the last call for specifying a vertex!
```

You can not group glColor, glNormal and the other calls. *But then you should not use immediate mode anyway!* It has been deprecated since 1996, when OpenGL-1.1 did introduce *vertex arrays*. Do you really insist on using technology that has been outdated for almost 20 years?

Comment: Each glTexCoord2f is followed by a glVertex3f call, in the same line.

Comment: @aslg: Yes, but only in some of the lines. In others you don't touch the texture coordinate at all.

Comment: The OP is trying to render the texture on the front face only. You don't necessarily have to define the tex coords fo all vertices, but the other faces will appear to be black since they don't have tex coords.

Comment: @aslg: The problem is, that glVertex will just use whatever glTexCoord was set last. glTexCoord and friends are not latching, i.e. calling glVertex is not "resetting" the other attributes to an unset state. If you don't want to texture the face in question you have to start a new primitive with texturing disabled.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I agree anyhow that it's best to set the texture coords for all vertices even if you want only one face. But I didn't know that the coords that were set last would still be used. (I tested this code and faces with no defined tex coords were black, so it was probably due to my image being mostly black and the last tex coord were a black texel?) I didn't downvote but I'll upvote now.